# can we pass command line argument to ant target

Tags: ant

How can we pass command line argument to ant target

for example I have target in build.xml defined as below

```
 <target name="test">
      <echo>Hello,</echo>
   </target>
```

if I invoke ant as
cmd>ant -buildfile build.xml test USERNAME

It should print echo as "Hello, USERNAME"

is it possible some way?
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ant -buildfile build.xml test USERNAME` would mean run the two targets, `test` and `USERNAME` (see [Ant manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)).

Instead, do `ant -buildfile build.xml -Dname=USERNAME test` and

```
<target name="test">
    <echo>Hello, ${name}</echo>
</target>
```